# What is the status of A28 Aire Sarthe Touraine

Tags: france, road-trips

Could anyone confirm the status of this aire de service on the A28?

[Aire Sarthe Touraine](http://www.bonial.fr/Magasins/Coemont/Flunch-autoroute-A28-Aire-de-Sartre-Touraine/v-f401112356)
72500 Dissay Sous Courcillon

The website shows 
[image]

naming the restaurant as Flunch.

[The website of the operator](http://en.sites.vinci-autoroutes.com/) specifies that this aire exists, however Google Maps is most insistent that it is "permanently closed".

While Google Maps refers only to Flunch, if this **is** closed then it makes me doubt the veracity of the operator's website.

I would very much like to know if I can rely on there at least being a coffee available.

[image: Google maps info]

Comment: Google says that flunch, which seems to be some restaurant, is closed, not the service area itself

Comment: So far as I can see Google says nothing about the service area; but my concern is that Flunch is referenced from the operator's website, if that is inaccurate then can I count on any other aspect being open? This seems to be the only option for food and fueld between Le Mans and quite a bit south of Tours.

Comment: It's *Sarthe*, not *Sartre*...

Comment: @fkraiem it's even misspelled on the website ! Good catch

Comment: Couldn't find that branch on Flunch's website by the way, try calling the listed phone number ?

Comment: Well, tell that to Google Maps, Im having an existential crisis ;-) I noticed the differences in spelling, but if you search for Sarthe you get somewhere very different, if you click on the map at the position of the aire GoogleMaps shows the title correctly "Aire Sarthe Touraine " but the closed Flunch. If your search for Sartre Touraine GoogleMaps shows the correct position of the services with no info.

Comment: The evidence (no Flunch location on Flunch website) begins to point to at least some of the info of the autoroute operator's website being out of date. My French isn't good enough to allow me to call the aire and say "Hello, do you exist?"

Comment: What's so interesting about that location? Maybe ask a wider question on restaurant options in that area?

Comment: First, specifically, it's on a route I happen to be taking, and is the only aire-de-service on a stretch from Le Mans to south of Toures - if I can't stop there for food then I either need to add time to leave the autoroute and go into a town (I'm perfectly capable of find somewhere if I need to, but I don't want to spend the time) or adjust my other planned stops. Of more importance it cuts to whether we can trust the Vinci web-site which lists the facilities: it says there is a Flunch, GoogleMaps seems to says it's shut. If I can't trust this Vinci entry how can I trust all the other ones?

Answer (score 4):

It's definitely still there. Busy but fine. Cafe, sandwiches and fuel.

Comment: Can you expand a bit more ? Were you there, how long ago ? Or did you just read this online somewhere ?

Answer (score 4):

[The official site](http://www.flunch.fr/) states that "*Certains restaurants flunch apparaissent comme fermés ce jour sur Google. Il s’agit d’un incident technique, vos restaurants flunch sont bien ouverts et vous accueilleront avec plaisir pour un moment flunchant*" ("Some Flunch restaurants arrear as closed on Google today. This is due to a a technical incident. Your Flunch restaurants are open and will welcome you with pleasure for a «flunchy» moment")
[image: Screenshot from the site]

The restaurant does not appear when I look with [their search engine](http://restaurant.flunch.fr/) but it may be a consequence of the same incident.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am now determined to ensure that I experience un moment flunchant ;-)